# Docker configuration with official Airflow and Spark

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, airflow

I'm currently building a set of big data tools in Docker.

I'm using Ubuntu 22 locally. Python in its latest version, Apache Spark 3.5.0 and Airflow 2.7.3.

I'm having trouble configuring Spark with Airflow. I've read a lot here on this topic and have been looking for relevant solutions with as few dependencies and add-ons as possible.

Ideally, I'd just like to extend the official Airflow image with Spark. But I keep getting the error: **HADOOP_CONF_DIR** and **YARN_CONF_DIR** are not defined.

If I've understood Spark correctly, I don't necessarily need to define these variables if I'm using Spark in standalone mode. But I'm not sure which mode I really need in this particular case.

I'm installing the Spark image inside Airflow so that it can access it, but it might be better to create Spark containers separately and have them communicate on the same Network.

I want to retrieve data from an API with my Python script, then store it on AWS S3. I then transform it with Spark, and store it again.

Thanks in advance for your time. I'll keep looking and update this post as I progress.
I remain available if I need to add further information.

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.7.3
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR             - Base path to which all the files will be volumed.
#                                Default: .
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Use this option ONLY for quick checks. Installing requirements at container
#                                startup is done EVERY TIME the service is started.
#                                A better way is to build a custom image or extend the official image
#                                as described in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  # image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.7.3}
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    # Use simple http server on scheduler for health checks
    # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/check-health.html#scheduler-health-check-server
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    # WARNING: Use _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS option ONLY for a quick checks
    # for other purpose (development, test and especially production usage) build/extend Airflow image.
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    # .env in your local environment can override any environment variable defined here
    OWNER: ${OWNER:-}
    API_KEY_ALPHA_VANTAGE: ${API_KEY_ALPHA_VANTAGE:-}
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:-}
    AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY: ${AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY:-}
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      # yamllint disable rule:line-length
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO && gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  ######################################################
  # SPARK SERVICES
  ######################################################

  spark-master:
    image: apache/spark-py:latest
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
    networks:
      - airflow-network

  spark-worker-1:
    image: apache/spark-py:latest
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/spark:/opt/spark/work-dir
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark-master
      - SPARK_CONN_ID=spark_default
      - SPARK_CONN_TYPE=spark
      - SPARK_CONN_HOST=spark-master
      - SPARK_CONN_PORT=7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    networks:
      - airflow-network

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:

networks:
  airflow-network:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG SPARK_VERSION="3.5.0"
ARG HADOOP_VERSION="3"

FROM apache/airflow:2.7.3
LABEL authors="JLJQ"
USER root

# Setup Command
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget \
  && apt-get install -y procps \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/spark \
  && chown -R airflow: /usr/local/spark

COPY requirements.txt /

# Setup Java
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         openjdk-11-jre-headless \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

# Setup Spark
ENV SPARK_VERSION="3.5.0"
ENV HADOOP_VERSION="3"
ENV SPARK_HOME /usr/local/spark
RUN cd "/tmp" && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" && \
    tar -xvzf "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" && \
    mkdir -p "${SPARK_HOME}/bin" && \
    mkdir -p "${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars" && \
    cp -a "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}/bin/." "${SPARK_HOME}/bin/" && \
    cp -a "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}/jars/." "${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars/" && \
    rm "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" && \
    rm -rf "/tmp/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}"

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r /requirements.txt
```